# How to theoretically determine if a hydrate of a salt precipitates out of solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, extraction, precipitation, salt

In a solid-liquid extraction simulation process, there are multiple salts that precipitate in the solution. But how do I determine if these salts are hydrates or not? To give an example:

$$\ce{Ca3(PO4)2(aq) + 3 H2SO4(aq) -> 3 CaSO4(s) + 2 H3PO4(aq)}$$

$$\ce{Ca3(PO4)2(aq) + 3 H2SO4(aq) + 6 H2O -> 3 CaSO4.2H2O(s) + 2 H3PO4(aq)}$$

To give another example, $\ce{MgSO4(aq)}$ also forms but is made solid when it is dried afterwards. It has more than 10 hydrate forms besides the anhydrous form.

Comment: When produced in water at room temperature, precipitates are always under a hydrated form. For example $\ce{CaSO4}$ is always precipitated as $\ce{CaSO4·2H2O}$